# VB,Net - how to convert string "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt" to datetime

Tags: vb.net

everytime i try to convert astring to datetime i get exception.

this is the format of the date string
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt"

this is the string value for example
"‎2019-09-20 7:20 PM"

this is sample code:

```
    Dim DateTimeNow As DateTime = Now
    Dim str As String = "‎2019-09-20 7:20 PM"


    If DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, DateTimeNow) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Format good")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Format Error")
    End If
```

Edit:
i tried this sample code and same exception:

```
    Dim DateTimeNow As DateTime = Now
    Dim str As String = "‎2019-09-20 7:20 PM"
    Dim possibleDateFormat As String() = {"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm tt", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm tt", "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt"}

    If DateTime.TryParseExact(str, possibleDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, DateTimeNow) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Format good")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Format Error")
    End If
```

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to have both "HH" and "tt" in the same format specifier. Have you read about date/time formats? "HH" is specifically two-digit 24-hour time and "tt" is specifically "AM" or "PM", which are exclusively for 12-hour time. Do you want 12-hour or 24-hour time? If you want the former then use "h:mm tt" if you're not going to pad the hour with zeroes or "hh:mm tt" if you are. If you want 24-hour time then use "HH:mm" and pad the hour with zeroes, or "H:mm" if you're not padding.

Comment: Hello, i tried all format as you can see in the sample code part 2. Im just trying to take the string and put in a datetime variable. I didnt want to parse the string based on delimiter and use the proper conversion way. If you have working code in c# or vb that can convert this exact string to datetime please share.

Comment: I just copied your code directly into VS 2022 and there is an erroneous Unicode character (u+200E) at the start of the date/time string. I deleted that character and it worked exactly as you expect. I suggest that you delete that line and retype it and it will probably work. For future reference, this is why you should examine each and every character of a `String` that is not working the way you think it should. There are a number of Unicode characters that don't have a visual representation. I'm using the latest version of VS 2022 and it does display that character in the code window.

Comment: thank you this is the issue. using encoding to remove unicode made it work after

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to specify a second possible format for single-digit hours:

`yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt`

because the date literal `7:20 AM` does not *exactly* match `HH:mm tt`. That's how exact the "Exact" in `TryParseExact` is.

Also, the `h` in previously `H:mm` needs to be lowercase, because when `tt` applies because of AM/PM, it is no longer treated as a 24h format and fails because capital H specifically parses the 24h, AM/PM-less format.

Working example:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim DateTimeNow As Date = Now
        Dim str As String = "2019-09-20 7:20 PM"

        If Date.TryParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, DateTimeNow) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Format good")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Format Error")
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

It is still possible to do this with one function call, by using [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tryparseexact(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-string()-system-iformatprovider-system-globalization-datetimestyles-system-datetime@)) of the function which takes an array of alternative format strings instead of a single format string.

Comment: hello, i tried your format with same error

        Dim str As String = "‎2019-09-20 7:20 PM"


        If DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, DateTimeNow) Then
            Console.WriteLine("Format good")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Format Error")
        End If

Comment: oh sorry. the H needs to be lowercase h because when you're using AM/PM designator, it is no longer 24h format but 12h format, and this is what H vs. h means in the format string. Also, the 0200 unicode character at the beginning of the format string (some kind of invisible white space?) that jmcilhinney also mentioned in the comments, made a difference. Visual Studio 2022 shows it in color.